# Identify duplicate record in Dataframe

Tags: sql, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a dataframe as below which identifies full name of any person:

```
-------------------
| f_name | l_name |
-------------------
| abc    | xyz    |
| xyz    | abc    |
| pqr    | lmn    |
-------------------
```

Here the second row is basically same as first row.

Consider the case where an entry has come in the data where by mistake last name is put under first name(**f_name**) and first name is put under last name(**l_name**)

How can I identify and drop/resolve such duplicate/erroneous records in spark dataframe?

Desired Result:

```
-------------------
| f_name | l_name |
-------------------
| abc    | xyz    |
| pqr    | lmn    |
-------------------
```

Solution could be with `udf` or `SQL` or both. Thnx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `dropDuplicates` function available for `Dataset` with the proper key:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("abc", "xyz"),
  ("xyz", "abc"),
  ("pqr", "lmn")
).toDF("f_name", "l_name")

df.withColumn("key", array_sort(array('f_name, 'l_name))).dropDuplicates("key")

+------+------+----------+
|f_name|l_name|       key|
+------+------+----------+
|   pqr|   lmn|[lmn, pqr]|
|   abc|   xyz|[abc, xyz]|
+------+------+----------+
```

Comment: @Kombajin Great answer!. Could you also please help with converting that "key" column array to a column in the final df? Say as column (full_name) value (abc_xyz). I tried converting to rdd and then split each Row(0) but I am getting WrappedArray(abc_xyz)

Comment: @Harshv: Review the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html) to find `array_join` function. Try: `.withColumn("full_name", array_join('key, " ")`.